# Preferred way to write custom iterators in C++17

Tags: c++, iterator, c++17

Beginning with C++17 inheriting from `std::iterator<...>` is deprecated. Instead one should specialize the `std::iterator_traits<...>` for the own iterator type.

I used to write my iterator class as nested types in the container classes they belong to.

Trying to partial specialize the `std::iterator_traits<C<T>>` leads to a non-deducible context for the value type `T` for my container `C`.

The question: should I now (as of C++17) define my iterator classes *outside* my container classes?

Comment: "Instead one should specialize the `std::iterator_traits<...>` for the own iterator type." Where did you hear this from?

Comment: If it is deprecated to derived from `std::interator<...>` my thought was, I had to specialize `std::iterator_traits`

Comment: Well, I also read this in the "C++17 STL Cookbook" by Jacek Galowicz.

Comment: Specializing `std::iterator_traits` might be useful for some functions that needs it, but it's not necessary. On the other hand, inheriting from `std::iterator` wasn't necessary either.

Comment: As per the book "Until C++17, it was encouraged to let iterator types just inherit from
std::iterator<...>, which automatically populates our class with all the
type definitions. This still works, but it is discouraged since C++17" so its not deprecated

Comment: @HariomSingh `std::iterator` *is* deprecated in C++17. That is why its use is discouraged.

Comment: Please look at http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator/iterator, the template `std::iterator` is deprecated.

Comment: And algorithms like `std::copy` clearly need a specialization of `std::iterator_traits<>`.

Comment: @wimalopaan the non-specialized `std::iterator_traits` is fine for most custom iterators. You don't need to specialize unless your iterator is special.

Comment: Why would they need a specialization of `iterator_traits`? The only thing `iterator_traits` does is exposing iterator own type aliases. If your iterator is implemented properly, the defaut version would work just fine.

Comment: The usual solution is to provide the appropriate typedefs in the iterator itself. That "cookbook" sounds like complete nonsense.

Comment: Well, I did that for the five, but I still get the errors from `std::copy` needing the the `std::iterator_traits` specialization ... don't know whats going on here. I'm using `g++-7.1` with `-std=c++17`

Comment: Are your typedefs public?

Comment: Yes: public typedefs for at least `value_type` and `iterator_category` in the nested, public custom iterator class.

Comment: You need all five.

Comment: Ok, very misleading error, since that only complains about `value_type` and `iterator_category`. I was missing `difference_type` since its not needed for my case, and I thought it would be best in this case not to define the typedef for it. Now I defined it to `void` and its ok. Thanks very much!

Comment: @Holt You *do* need all five. Miss one and `iterator_traits` won't give you any.

Comment: @T.C. You're right, I misunderstood the quote from cppreference.